# Refresh DOM after removing attribute without refreshing page like chrome does

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div element that looks like this after loading the page. "ui-sortable" attribute adds a class ui-sortable after load which helps me to drag and drop child divs

```
    <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" id="questions" class="ui-sortable">
       <div id="question2">...</div>
       <div id="question3">...</div>
    </div>
```

if I mouseover #question3, i remove ui-sortable class. but it still drags and drops. I guess DOM event is loaded on startup, and even i remove the class it still knows the binded event.

Also, If I remove the class from Chrome inspect element by clicking edit as html option and remove it, it works ok without a page refresh.

So How can I achieve that? Disabling event?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the class, [disable the event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable):

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "disable" );
```

Comment: That does not work out, ui-draggable-disabled class appear in the div element but stills drags

Comment: Are you using the ***same*** selector that you set the `draggable` widget with?

Comment: Yes, divs are in a ng-repeat of angularjs, maybe this doesnot work out. İ also triedevery selector